# splitting a column into two based on if conditions getting prior row

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyr, stringr

I have a data frame as follows:

```
 A<- c ('Proceed', 'John Smith', 'K University, J.smith@Ku.edu', 'Arun Pandey', 'P.S University, a.pan@ps.ed', 'This is a test')

new <- data.frame (A)
```

I would like to split the data frame column A into two rows: 1) containing the email address(containing all the rows from the data frame) and 2) containing the name which appears a row before the email address row. Any suggestions?

```
    email                              name 
    K University, J.smith@Ku.edu       John Smith 
    P.S University, a.pan@ps.ed        Arun Pandey
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the index of rows where 'A' column have `@` character with `grep`.  Then use  it to subset the rows of the data in creating the two column dataset

```
i1 <- grep("@", new$A)
data.frame(email = new$A[i1], name = new$A[i1-1])
#                         email        name
#1 K University, J.smith@Ku.edu  John Smith
#2  P.S University, a.pan@ps.ed Arun Pandey
```